# How do you create a bootable Linux UEFI USB drive

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, uefi

I am trying to install Fedora 25 along side Windows 10 with UEFI booting enabled and SecureBoot disabled. I am using Rufus but I can't seem to get the Linux Live image to boot when I select the USB drive.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what guide are you following??
I followed http://www.fosslinux.com/888/how-to-create-fedora-live-usb-drive-on-windows.htm this guide a few moths ago try this guide i think the problem is with the rufus setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your boot settings are not correct.
Steps to take: 
1. Research the required BIOS settings for your manufacturer. Secure boot should be disabled but occasionally (like with Asus) there are other settings to adjust.

2. Consult this link: http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install
   I know that it is for Kali but it should work for you. I have not used Rufus before but a lot of those tools do not work right with UEFI. Use the Win32 Disk Imager mentioned in the article and it should correctly install the OS.