# What's the difference between EFI booting a USB versus a hard disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, uefi, bootable-media

Can you please tell me the difference between EFI booting a USB and EFI booting a hard drive, as wheen installing a Linux image on the USB using Rufus, it's booting, but when the same image is installed on a hard drive, it's not detected by the UEFI firmware:

- `fdisk -l` output: [image: fdisk screenshot]

Comment: The USB is just running in live mode, I suspect you are not correctly making the hard disk bootable. Which Linux are you installing?

Comment: What is live mode.. I am installing Linux yocto image

Comment: Is this dual boot or are you only installing yocto

Comment: Check this answer -  https://superuser.com/questions/1203110/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-linux-uefi-usb-drive/1203144#1203144

Comment: I am trying to install yocto

Comment: Try using the tool recommended in that link I shared. Rufus doesn't always play well with uefi

Comment: Rufus is working well with USB pen drive but not with USB to SSD drive

Comment: I know but usb and your hard drive are not the same thing. Try the other tool and I suspect it will boot - Also as the link recommends research your system and ensure you have configured everything in BIOS correctly.

Comment: @md.jamal _(Please do not screenshot terminal output, instead please copy/paste content into a code box.)_ There is no difference between EFI booting a USB vs HDD and there's only two reasons it would boot one and not the other: [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) is enabled _(it shouldn't be since  its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017)_ or the partition table isn't GPT _(CSM Mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment and, when enabled, MBR is used)_

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are having uefi firmware and you are trying to boot from USB.

First of all you need to use GPT partition, for your USB to get detected in the uefi boot priority option.

The next thing that you should be careful about is, your Linux iso image. It has to be compatible with efi, otherwise Rufus will not format the USB. What I mean by compatible is, you need to have efi firmware(*.efi) for your platform in the efi/boot/ directory in you Linux iso image. You can check that by mounting Linux iso.